Applying $\frac{\text{lcm}(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$ repeatedly to numbers on a board
Question: The integers $1,2,\cdots,10$ are written on a blackboard. Every minute, Sophia picks two of the numbers $a$ and $b$ on the board and replaces them with $\frac{\text{lcm}(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$ until there is only one number left on the board. Find the maximum possible value of this number left over at the end.
The answer to this question is $\boxed{252}$.

I began by using the identity $\text{lcm}(a,b) \cdot \gcd(a,b)=ab$, which I used to deduce that $$\frac{\text{lcm}(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}=\frac{ab}{(\gcd(a,b))^2}=\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} \cdot \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}$$ or simply the product of $ab$ after all common factors are "removed".
I also began figuring out the answer for small values of $n$, and found that:

If the integer $1$ is written on the board, then the maximum possible value for the ending number is $1$.

If the integers $1,2$ are written on the board, then the maximum possible value of the ending number is $2$.

If the integers $1,2,3$ are written on the board, then the maximum possible value of the ending number is $6$.

If the integers $1,2,3,4$ are written on the board, then the maximum possible value of the ending number is $6$.

If the integers $1,2,3,4,5$ are written on the board, then the maximum possible value of the ending number is $30$.


At this point, I was quite stuck, and all I could think of was how to "remove" the common prime factors optimally in light of the fact that there would be a total of $9$ applications of $\frac{\text{lcm}(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$. However, I couldn't really conclude anything, but turning to OEIS gave me the sequence A056040, the swinging factorial. (Link to sequence here: https://oeis.org/A056040) [EDIT: THE OEIS PART IS WRONG]
Any insight/hints would be greatly appreciated (I would like to be able to solve this question without using outside resources).

Have you noticed $\mathrm{lcm}(\mathrm{lcm}(a,b),c) = \mathrm{lcm}(a,b,c)$, $\mathrm{lcm}(\mathrm{lcm}(a,b),\mathrm{lcm}(c,d)) = \mathrm{lcm}(a,b,c,d)$, and similarly for the $\mathrm{gcd}$.  You might have seen this when your "$1,2,3,4$" and "$1,2,3,4,5$" examples gave you the same result no matter what order you paired numbers.

For $1,2,\dots,8$, the re-ordered $7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 8$ will give $280$, different that  the sequence A056040, which is $70$. Neither is it A034386.
The first 10 values I numerically calculated are $1,2,6,6,30,20,140,280,2520,252$.

Here’s an elementary method which works for small $n$ such as given in this problem. Consider the numbers written in their prime factorisation: $$1, \ 2, \ 3, \ 2^2, \ 5, \ 2\times 3, \ 7, \ 2^3, \ 3^2, \ 2\times 5$$
One must understand what the “operation” does to the numbers. When you apply the operation to two numbers, say $n_1=2^a\cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c\cdot 7^d$ and $n_2=2^A\cdot 3^B\cdot 5^C \cdot 7^D$; they are replaced by a new number which is $2^{|A-a|}\cdot 3^{|B-b|} \cdot 5^{|C-c|} \cdot 7^{|D-d|}$. Thus after applying the operation adequate number of times such that one number is left on the board, the number left will be of the form $$2^q\cdot 3^r \cdot 5^s \cdot 7^t$$ where $q$, $r$, $s$ and $t$ are some numbers formed by taking repeated differences of pairs of exponents of $2, 3, 5, 7$ respectively (take difference of one pair of exponents, then taking that difference as a single exponent, take its difference with another exponent, and so on).
Thus, for the prime factor $7$, only the number $7$ contributes an exponent of $1$; so $t=1$ always.
For prime factor of $5$, both $5$ and $10$ contribute exponent of $1$ each, so there is only one possible difference of exponents which is $0$. So $s=0$.
For $3$, we have exponents of $1, 1, 2$ contributed respectively by $3$, $6$ and $9$; so there are two ways of taking repeated difference of the exponents in pairs, ie finding the various values of $||x_1-x_2|-x_3|$ where two of the $x_i$ are $1$ and one of them is $2$; which then yields the two possible values $2-(1-1)$ or $ 1-(2-1)$, so either $r=0$ or $r=2$.
For the prime factor $2$ we have the exponents $1,2,1,3,1$. So one has to find the maximum of $\left|\left|\left|\left|x_1-x_2\right|-x_3\right|-x_4\right|-x_5\right|$ where three of the $x_i$ are $1$, one of the $x_i$ is $2$, and the last remaining $x_i$ is $3$. Clearly the difference $\le 3$. With some effort, one finds that $2$ is the maximum this difference can obtain. Thus for maximising the last number $q=2$.
Thus the maximum number that may be left on the board (ie, an upper bound for the last number if one can maximise individual powers) is at most $$\boxed {2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^0 \cdot 7 =\color{teal}{252}}$$
This upper bound can be achieved in the following way thereby showing that it is a maximum: $$\begin{align}
1,\color{blue}{2}, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\color{blue}{10}\\
1,3,\color{green}{4}, 5, \color{blue}5, \color{green}6, 7, 8, 9\\
1,3,\color{teal}{5,5}, \color{green}6, 7, 8, 9\\
1, \color{teal}{1}, 3, \color{magenta}6, 7, \color{magenta}8, 9 \\
1, \color{orange}1, 3, \color{orange}7, 9, \color{magenta}{12} \\
1, \color{pink}3, \color{orange}7, 9, \color{pink}{12} \\
1, \color{pink}4, \color{cyan}7, \color{cyan}9 \\ 
\color{gray}1, \color{gray}4, \color{cyan}{63} \\
\color{gray}4, 63\\
252
\end{align}$$

P.S.: We have shown that $252$ is an upper bound which can be achieved if there exists a sequence of operations which can allow us to maximise both $3$ and $2$ (there could be cases where maximising $3$ makes it so that we are no longer able to maximise $2$ since it depends on how we arrange the $x_i$’s in the equations). With an example we show this upper bound is achievable, thus $252$ is the maximum.

For example if we had $24, 36, 54$ on the board; then the maximum power of $2$ would be $2^2$ while the maximum power of $3$ would be $3^2$; but there exists no sequence of steps s.t. $2^2 \cdot 3^2 = 36$ be achieved. Thus, $36$ here is just an upper bound. To solve this example, we know that the power of $2$ is either $1$ or $4$, and for three it is either $1$ or $9$, so we can iterate over the $4$ possibilities to reject $36$ and see that $9$, $4$, and $1$ are all possible end results at the end of the algorithm.

I'd consider what happens when you combine a multiple of a prime with a number that is not a multiple of the prime, and what happens when you multiply a multiple of a prime with another multiple of a prime, and what happens when you combine a number with $1$ and so on.
It's easy to make the following claims.  There will always be exactly one multiple of $7$ (which will not be a multiple of $7^2$) on the board and therefore the final result will be a multiple of $7$.  Why?  Every time you multiply $7k$ by $m$ where $m$ is not a multiple of $7$ you get (because $7$ and $m$ are relatively prime, as is $7$ and $k$) $\frac {\text{lcm}(7k, m)}{\gcd(7k,m)}=\frac {7\text{lcm}(k,m)}{\gcd(k,m)}=7d$ where $d =\frac {\text{lcm}(k,m)}{\gcd (k,m)}$ and $d$ is relatively prime to $7$. So always the one multiple of will combine with a non-multiple of $7$ to get a single multiple of $7$ and the number of multiples of $7$ will never change.
The number $1$ will vanish the first time it's combined with any other number and the other number will remain unchanged.  That's because $\frac {\text{lcm}(1,a)}{\gcd(1,a)}=\frac a1 = a$.
The will be on the board two multiples of $5$ until the combine with each other and that will result in no multiples of $5$ on the board.  We start with two multiples of $5$ namely, $5$ and $10$.  When one of these combines with a non-multiple of $5$ the result is $\frac {\text{lcm}(5k,m)}{\gcd(5k,m)}=\frac{5\text{lcm}(k,m)}{\gcd(k,m)}=5d$ (where $d$ is $\frac{\text{lcm}(k,m)}{\gcd(k,m)}$) but when we combine $5j$ with $5j$ we get $\frac {\text{lcm}(5k,5j)}{\gcd(5k,5j)}=\frac {5\text{lcm}(k,j)}{5\gcd(k,j)}=\frac {\text{lcm}(k,j)}{\gcd(k,j)}$ which is relatively prime to $5$.  So the final result will not be a multiple of $5$.
This leaves only multiples of $2$ and $3$ but unlike $5$ and $7$ we can have numbers that are multiples of powers of $2$ and $3$.
So what happens if two multiples of equal powers of $p$ collide?  Say $kp^a$ combines with $mp^a$.  THen the result is $\frac {\text{lcm}(kp^a,mp^a)}{\gcd(kp^a,mp^a)}=\frac {p^a\text{lcm}(k,m)}{p^a\gcd(k,m)} = d$.  The prime vanishes.
But what happens if two unequal powers of primes met?  So $a < b$ and we have $kp^a$ and $mp^b$ then $\frac {\text{lcm}(kp^a,mp^b)}{\gcd(kp^a,mp^b)}=\frac {p^b\text{lcm}(k,m)}{p^a\text{lcm}(k,m)}= p^{b-a}$.  The power is reduced.
Now we have start with three multiples of $3$:  $3,6,9=3^2$.  We can have have $3$ or $6$ (or one of their descendants) combine with the $9$ (or descendant) to get the $9=3^2$ reduced and then have the the two remaining multiples of $3$ combine to have an end result not a multiple of $3$.  If we could have $3$ and $6$ (or descendants) collide with each other first.  The the descendants of $9$ will always be a multiple of $9$.  So the highest possible value can be multiple of $9$. (Otherwise we can have a result that is not a multiple of $3$ at all.  I don't see how we can get an end result that is a multiple of just $3$ however.)
Now we have lots of multiple of $2$ we have: $2, 4=2^2, 6, 8=2^3, 10$.  The $4=2^2$ going to have to collide with anothoer multiple of $2$ eventually.  If in combines with a descendant of $8=2^3$ we end with a simple multiple of $2$.  We will have four of them (the descendant of $2,6$ and $10$ and the collision of $4$ with $8$) and they will pairwise collide leaving us with something relatively prime to $2$.
Or we can have the $4$ collide with a descendant of $2,6$ or $10$ and the result will be three simple multiples of $2$ and a multiple of $8$.  The multiple of $8$ will have to collide with one of the other multiples of $2$ eventually to result in a multiple of $4$.  But in need not collide with any other if the other two collide with each other.
So the absolute maximum that can be left will be $7\times 9\times 4=252$
And example of this can be:
$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$. To assure we end up with a multiple of $9$ have the simple multiples of $3$ collide with each other to cancel out.  Have the $3$ collide with the $6$ to get $\frac {6}3=2$.
$1,2,2,4,5,7,8,9,10$. (Now we have assured we will remain with multiple of $9$.
To assure we end up with multiple of $4$, have a simple multiple of $2$ collide with the $4$. Have $2$ collide with $4$ to get $\frac 42=2$.
$1,2,2,5,7,8,9,10$.  Now the simple multiples of $2$ can collide with each other but as there are an odd number of them there will be one let and that must collide with the $8$.  So collide the two $2$s to get $\frac 22=1$ leaving $10$ as the last simple multiple of $2$.
$1,1,5,7,8,9,10$.  Now we only have one simple multiple of $2$  Collide it with $8$ to get $\frac {\text{lcm}(10,8)}{\gcd(10,8)}=\frac {40}{2}=20$.
$1,1,5,7,20,9$. Now we have $20$ as the only multiple of $2^2=4$ and that assures the final result will be a multiple of $4$.  From here one we can do what we want.
The multiples of $5$ will have to collide so do that now.  $\frac {\text{lcm}(5,20)}{\gcd(5,20)}=\frac {20}5 = 4$.
$1,1,7,4,9$.  Get rid of the $1$s.  Let's collide one with $7$ and the other with $4$.  (Or whatever...)
$7,4,9$.  Now we have three relative prime results.  $\frac {\text{\lcm}(4,7)}{\gcd(4,7)} = \frac {4\times 7}1$.
$28,9$ and finally $\frac {\text{\lcm}(28,9)}{\gcd(28,9)}=28\times 9=252$
